# Creating module can display map in page or block in drupal

Tags: 7, hooks, routes, blocks

I have two days I'm trying to develop my custom module.
I want to display map in block but nothing happened.
how i can called css an js file and show them in page or block?

```
function exemple_init() {
  drupal_add_js('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', 'external');
}

function exemple_block_info() {
  $blocks['exemple'] = array(
    'info' => t('Google Map Exemple'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function exemple_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'exemple':
        $block['content'] = '';
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly adding a JS file globally in `hook_init` function is wrong unless you want the file to be loaded on each page of your site. To add a JS file to a block use the `#attached` property in `hook_block_view`

eg:

```
'#attached' => array(
      'css' => array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mymodule.css',
      ),
      'js' => array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.js',
    ),
  ),
```

Secondly, I assume you want to show an address from Google Maps in your block.
In that case pull the embed code from Google Maps https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3544418?hl=en
and use that embed code in the block.

Sample Code for it: http://pastebin.com/5h1c2SBU

Though still curious about the JS file.

Comment: Agreed. And even simpler for a static location to just add a block via block UI and paste code in there with appropriate filter setting.